# Write stdout to two different files (one overwrite, one append) in bash

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, tee

I have a bunch of experiments that are organized by `group` and by `number`.  I have 3 different `groups` and for `number`, I wish to run 2 different experiments.  In other words, I have the following experiments to run:

```
group A, 1
group A, 2
group B, 1
group B, 2
group C, 1
group C, 2
```

Every time I run a program that prints the results of the experiment to stdout, I want those results to be put into a text file.  I want a separate text file for the results of each `group` and `number` combination, and also a separate text file for the results of each `group` containing all the `number` runs.

So, here is my bash script that runs all these experiments:

```
#!/bin/bash

groups="A B C"
numbers="1 2"

rm *.txt

for g in $groups; do

    # Set the group settings based on the value of $g

    for n in $numbers; do

        # Set the number settings based on the value of $n

        ./myprogram >> $g-results.txt

    done

done
```

Using the above code, I end up with these text files:

```
A-results.txt
B-results.txt
C-results.txt
```

But I also want to have the text files:

```
A-1-results.txt
A-2-results.txt
B-1-results.txt    
B-2-results.txt
C-1-results.txt
C-2-results.txt
```

How can I change my `./myprogram...` command so that the output is concatenated (`>>`) to one text file (like I'm already doing) and overwritten (`>`) to another (like I want to be doing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tee` command to "split" standard output to multiple destinations.

```
./myprogram | tee "$g-$number-results.txt" >> $g-results.txt
```

`tee` writes its standard input to one (or more) named files as well as to standard output, so the above pipeline writes the output of each instance of `myprogram` to a unique per-run output file, as well as aggregating output for all `$g` runs to one file.

You can also aggregate the output of the inner `for` loop instead of appending to the file.

```
for g in $groups; do
    # Set the group settings based on the value of $g
    for n in $numbers; do
        # Set the number settings based on the value of $n
        ./myprogram | tee "$g-$number-results.txt"
    done > "$g-results.txt"
done
```

Comment: Great!  Didn't know about `for` loop aggregation. Also wasn't aware that tee did multiple writes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already list the `tee` command:

```
./myprogram | tee $g-$n-results.txt >> $g-results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simple way instead of:

```
./myprogram >> $g-results.txt
```

You can capture the output once and write it twice:

```
$out=$(./myprogram)
echo "$out" >> "$g-results.txt"
echo "$out" > "$g-$n-results.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to scan and monitor the text file during runtime.  (I didn't mention this, but it's a requirement for me.)

Comment: oh ok in that case `tee` based answer may work better for you I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use tee twice.

myprog | tee -a appendFile.txt | tee overwriteFile.txt

Just like this it will also print to stdout. You could add something on the end to pipe it to something else if you wanted.

IF you needed to any manipulation in between sed is your friend.

Comment: True, but I believe you need to do it like this if you want one tee to append (-a) and the other to overwrite.