# redirect output file to another file in c

Tags: c, operating-system, fileoutputstream

In my program, the program is redirecting the output from stdout to src_file,
and now I want to redirect the output from the file to another file to make another analysis on the output and return again the analysis again to src_file

---

```
fflush(stdout);
orig_stdout = dup(fileno(stdout)); //saving original stdout
if(!freopen(ofile,"w+",stdout)) /*redirecting stdout to the file specified*/
```

I want to redirect the ouput now from the ofile to new another file.

Example:

ofile- get the whole outputs during the program is running.

I want to redirect some commands that omit output during the program is running to another file.
insead print to ofile, I want to print to anther file.

Comment: Terse has its place, but in this case a little more explanation would help to understand exactly what your objective is.  Show what you have tried, and why it did not work.   Include a [mcve].

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067608/645128) example uses a _tee_ command to split `stdout` into two files

Comment: Don't mess with `dup` and `freopen`, just open the appropriate file for output in your program or use separate processes for different tasks and use the shell to redirect their output as you wish.

Comment: ..so you want to redirect only specific parts of the first output file into a second file?  If that is the case, simply reading and parsing the desired contents from the first file,  into a second file can be done with two file descriptors and some calls to `fread()` and `fwrite()`, but I am not sure you can read from the first at the same instant it is being written to by `stdout` without setting  up a streaming algorithm, eg. pipes

Comment: Do you mean you want to have standard output going to two different destinations, or that you want to change its destination from one file to a different one?  And is it essential to manage that inside the program, or would it be acceptable to manage it externally, such as via a wrapper shell script?

Comment: John Bollinger - the 2nd choice, change the destination from one file to another file.